# Cannot update MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a collection from my database using de `node` module `mongoose`. The problem is with `$set` updates. Here is my code:

```
// Update a user
app.patch('/user/:user_id', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
    function (req, res) {
        var conditions  = { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.user_id)},
            updateObj   = { $set: req.body }; // {email : "bob@example.com", username: "bob"}

        User.update(conditions, updateObj, function callback (err, numAffected, rawResponse) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            // numAffected is the number of updated documents
            if (numAffected == 0) {
                res.json({ message: 'No user affected'});
                return;
            }

            res.json({ message: 'User updated'});
        });

});
```

If I update an existing key like `email`, it is updated. But if I want to add a new key, `numAffected` is always 0 and the `rawResponse` is `undefined`.

Any idea of what happens?

**Edit**

Here is my `Schema`:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email     : String,
  username  : String,
  password  : String
});
```

Comment: Can we see your schema?

Comment: Where have you imported `ObjectId` from? Mongoose will just autocast a valid string to an ObjectId value based on the "type" defined in the schema. ObjectId is the default so this is okay. Unless of course that your actual stored `_id` values are not ObjectId values. The other possibility is that your collection is actually named "user" when mongoose would be expecting "users" by default on the model. That's another common mistake.

Comment: Is the field you're trying to add in the schema?  If not, Mongoose will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set multiple fields in a document, you must set the **Multi** option in your config, otherwise Mongoose will ignore the continuation, and only update the first doc.

From the docs:

```
var conditions = { name: 'borne' }
  , update = { $inc: { visits: 1 }}
  , options = { multi: true };

Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);

function callback (err, numAffected) {
  // numAffected is the number of updated documents
});
```

Another note here: The numAffected should return as expected, but I can't find any documentation on their site about the raw response, but it should return as expected as well. Do you know of any documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really want to do with `mongoose` to update email and username of a user.

```
app.patch('/user/:user_id', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
    function (req, res) {

    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.user_id},
        {  
            $set: {
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email
            }
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            if (user) {
                res.json({message: 'User updated'});
            } else {
                res.json({message: 'User does not exist'});
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know I the updated items will be `email` or `username`. They may be something completely different like `last_name`

Comment: You cannot insert like `last_name` into database if it is not your **UserSchema**. According to your schema only, `username`, `email` and `password` can be updated.